# Should I vote to close if I'm not sure about the reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This has come up a few times, where I go to close vote a question and I don't find a reason that exactly fits, and I'm not sure what that best option would be. So I end up picking something that seems closest to me. I bet I'm pretty close most of the time.

But I'm wondering, does a close vote with the wrong reason do more harm than good?

Comment: VTC when you think the question should not be answered.  It is a given that the OP is never happy about it, speech is strictly limited and designed to minimize friction.  You'll have to make do with what's available, you can usually only can get "pretty close".

Comment: My observation from similar meta questions: when people have trouble picking a close vote, they should be downvoting.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't know why you are closing something, you shouldn't be closing it.

The whole reason that the close reasons are a limited list is that there are limited valid reasons to be closing something. Otherwise it could just be an open-ended question and you could fill it in with garbage.

Comment: But the list of close reasons, isn't perfect. One only need look at the list of "What should close reason be for X" or "Can we have close reason X" questions on meta

Comment: That makes no sense. The list of close reasons is what you are allowed to close for. If it isn't on the list, you shouldn't be closing it at all. Work through a request for the close reason if you don't agree, but don't justify abuse of the system by leaving a close vote that is 'close enough'.

Comment: There is an "other" option in "off-topic"

Answer (score 2):

> ...does a close vote with the wrong reason do more harm than good?

***Absolutely.***  I couldn't imagine anything that's more detrimental than a question closed for the wrong reasons.

If you're closing a question, then this means that **the question shouldn't be answered** in its current state due to it being off-topic, too broad, a duplicate, or unclear.  If it doesn't fit one of those reasons, then there really isn't any reason to try to force the issue of closure.

This isn't to say that it hasn't been done before; even now, we have a free-form close vote reason option.  However, please don't abuse that; use it only in certain, specific cases when you *know* a question is off-topic but there's no other reason that can justify its closure.

Comment: If a question should obviously be closed, I would think its better for it to be closed for the wrong reason than to stay open cluttering things up.

Comment: If it should obviously be closed, then there should be an obvious close reason to support it.  If there isn't, then it's not helping anything.

Comment: `If it should obviously be closed, then there should be an obvious close reason to support it.` this isn't the case. What built in close reason would you use for a question like `who won the Wimbledon men's single final in 2015`?

Comment: @MartinSmith:  I do mention custom close reasons.  That'd be a good usage of one.  Just don't abuse them; it's not a carte blanche way to close questions.