# Close reason guidance

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

This question: [What exactly is Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953743/what-exactly-is-visual-studio-code), basically asks what a certain piece of software is and I believe it should be deemed off-topic, but I couldn't decide on the better reason.

It's not really too broad, neither is it primarily opinion based. It could fall under the off-topic/general software/Super User reason.

I ended up choosing a custom close reason:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about
>   features of a product in development and as such is very likely to get
>   outdated in the future and thus less useful. The better source for
>   information on what VS Code is would be the product web site.

My question is if my assessment of the question is correct, and what close reason would have been appropriate?

Comment: He's basically asking: *I have this thing, what can I do with it?* and that fits too broad close reason.

Comment: @Braiam That was my feeling too, except I didn't think to use the _Too broad..._ reason.

Comment: "Visual Studio Code" is confusing, as it is not clear what it does, or why it was produced.    Yet it may become a very common tool.    Therefore the internet needs a good answer to the question "What exactly is Visual Studio Code".    Shame that none of the answers to the linked question come close to being useful.   However could be a a better fit on programer.se.

Comment: @IanRingrose: I disagree. A casual web search reveals the official webpage, which tells you what it is. I don't see why a SO question is needed to repeat that information. Shall we have a question "what is X" for all X?

Comment: when Microsoft ports something to Linux world, it certainly worth to ask some questions, especially how can a Linux user get profit of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[You should not vote to close a question if you can't determine the close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/should-i-vote-to-close-if-im-not-sure-about-the-reason).  Knowing that, your question boils down to determining whether that question fits a close reason.  I think that question still fits under the on-topic "software tools commonly used by programmers," so it's not blatantly off-topic.    And it's not unclear, too broad, or opinion-based either.  It isn't asking *for* a tool but rather a very **specific, answerable aspect** of it.  It just doesn't fit any close reason.

And even your custom close reason is not a good one.

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about features of a product in development and as such is very likely to get outdated in the future and thus less useful.

This may be true, but an *answerable* question about a future release can still be on-topic.  If it's not off-topic for any other reason, the community consensus is that [questions about future releases are still on-topic even if that information risks becoming obsolete in the future](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258504/are-questions-still-on-topic-if-they-solely-pertain-to-beta-software-and-will-li).

I think **the appropriate action would be to just leave it alone**.  Downvoting for "lack of research" is a possible action, but I personally wouldn't.

Comment: Good points, I guess I might have gotten carried away. My main reason was the part I included at the end of my custom close reason: _The better source for information on what VS Code is would be the product web site._  Guess a lack of research dw might have been more suitable (although a bit harsh maybe).

Comment: This answer was exactly the guidance I was looking for btw. My main purpose wasn't to get the question closed, although that was a foreseeable side-effect.

Comment: @jpw glad I could answer your underlying question.  Yeah close reasons are inherently subjective, and I _could_ see arguments going either way, but IMO this is not a bad question.  Unfortunately, some of the answers it got were really just copies of the accepted answer.  So I understand why people would want to close it.